# Как удалить класс в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Мне необходимо найти и удалить класс в html–странице под названиям `td-for-left-block`. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: $('.td-for-left-block').remove()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.td-for-left-block');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
```

Это если без jQuery. Есть более очевидный метод [Node.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) . IE его правда не поддерживает